# Mariadb 10.4 minor version review

Tags: mariadb

i am thinking about upgrading my mariadb production servers to 10.4 and i would like to ask you if you have any troubles with specific minor versions on 10.4.

So have you troubles with any version? Or what version are you running without any problems?

Comment: I have been watching MySQL and MariaDB for 20 years.  It is _very_ rare for a minor release (once it goes GA) to have a regression.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the latest *stable* release of MariaDB, that is [version 10.4.12](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10412-release-notes/), which was released on January 2020.

You will benefit the cumulative fixes of all previous subversions of 10.4 - the first stable subversion of 10.4 was [10.4.6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1046-release-notes/) (released in June 2019), so lot of work has been put into stabilizing it already.

Please note that version 10.5 is on its way too: alpha released 10.5.0 happened in December 2019; but as of today there is still no stable version available (10.5.1 - Beta, was released this month), so if you want something bullet-proof it is too early.

Of course, as always, you should install and test this in QA environment before moving to Production so you can ensure that everything works smoothly in *your* ecosystem.